# A value type "node" cannot be used to intialize an entity of type "struct node"

Tags: c, struct, queue, nodes

I have two functions in which one calls the other function and the title is the error I get. I am just wondering if there is a simple fix I am missing. Let me know if more information is needed. Thank you!

```
node createNode() {
newNode temp;//declare node
temp = (newNode)malloc(sizeof(struct node));//allocate memory
temp->next = NULL;//next point to null
return *temp;// return the new node
} 
void enqueue(queue* q, customer* data) {
// Create a new LL node
struct node* temp = createNode(data);//error line
```

Comment: `createNode` should return a `node *`.

Comment: `typedef struct node node;` existing anywhere?

Comment: Please be precise when posting code or errors. In your error message there seems to be a `*` missing. You try to initialize type `struct node*` not `struct node`.

Answer (score 0):

You want a return value of `struct node*`, so the return type should be `struct node*`.

Also naming the pointer to `struct node` as `newNode` looks very confusing (at least for me), so you shouldn't do that.

One more point is that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Finally, you should check of `malloc()` succeeded.

```
struct node* createNode() { /* use proper return type */
    /* use non-confusing type */
    struct node* temp;//declare node
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));//allocate memory
    if (temp == NULL) return temp; /* check if allocation succeeded */
    temp->next = NULL;//next point to null
    /* remove dereferencing */
    return temp;// return the new node
} 
void enqueue(queue* q, customer* data) {
    // Create a new LL node
    struct node* temp = createNode(data);//error line
```

Also it looks weird that the argument `data` is passed but ignored, but I won't fix this because I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Maybe using `calloc` instead of `malloc` would ensure the structure is fully initialized to zero. This is slightly slower but make sure everything has a known value and if something is forgotten later (like pointer initialization) it is likely produce a clear segment violation the a undefined behavior.